# Displaying nested association in view in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, model-associations

I have 3 models as below:

```
class Kick < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :offs
 has_many :retailers, :through => :off
end

class Retailer < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :offs
 has_many :kicks, :through => :off
end

class Off < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :kicks
 belongs_to :retailers
end
```

And I'm trying to display the name of the retailer in my 'show Kick view' as below:

```
  <% @kick.off.each do|off| %>
    <%= off.name %>
    <%= off.retailers.name %>
  <% end %>
```

Off.name displays fine but I cannot seem to index the retailer's name from this view. What am I missing?

Error:

```
undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: it should be `<% @kick.offs.each do |off|%>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Kick < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :offs
 has_many :retailers, :through => :offs
end

class Retailer < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :offs
 has_many :kicks, :through => :offs
end

class Off < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :kick
 belongs_to :retailer
end
```

also make sure you properly indexed the models in db

Answer (score 0):

```
class Kick < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :offs
 has_many :retailers, :through => :offs
end

class Retailer < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :offs
 has_many :kicks, :through => :offs
end

class Off < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :kick
 belongs_to :retailer
end


@kick = Kick.includes(:retailers => :offs).where('kicks.id' => 1).select('retailers.name, kicks.*')
```

Answer (score 0):

In the view it should be `kick.offs` not `kick.off`

```
<% @kick.offs.each do|off| %>
    <%= off.name %>
    <%= off.retailers.name %>
  <% end %>
```